# Parallel execution of Samplers in JMeter with different URL parameters

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

There is "ForEach" controller in JMeter which takes an array of items and executes a sampler with each item. This is very useful when you need to execute a sampler with different  parameters based on data received in previous request. However, "ForEach" controller runs samplers one after the other.

What I am looking for is, execute the samples in parallel. There is a plug in available in JMeter called, "bzm - Parallel Controller". However, this doesn't accept any input variable like "ForEach" controller does.

For example, I have following data in database. Author along with their books.

```html
[
     {
      "firstName": "William",
      "lastName":"Shakespeare",
      "Title": "Mr",
      "id": "1",
      "books": [
       {
        "id": "WS1",
        "title": "King John",
        "year":"1596"
       },
       {
        "id": "WS2",
        "title": "Julius Caesar",
        "year": "1599"
       },
       {
        "id": "WS3",
        "title": "Romeo and Juliet",
        "year": "1595"
       }
      ],
      "Nationality": "English"
     },
     {
      "firstName": "Sidney",
      "lastName":"Sheldon",
      "Title": "Mr",
      "id": "2",
      "books": [
       {
        "id": "SS1",
        "title": "The Naked Face",
        "year":"1969"
       },
       {
        "id": "SS2",
        "title": "A Stranger in the Mirror",
        "year": "1976"
       },
       {
        "id": "SS3",
        "title": "Bloodline",
        "year": "1977"
       }
      ],
      "Nationality": "American"
     },
     {
      
      "firstName": "Eiichiro",
      "lastName":"Oda",
      "Title": "Mr",
      "id": "3",
      "books": [
       {
        "id": "EO1",
        "title": "Wanted",
        "year":"1992"
       },
       {
        "id": "EO2",
        "title": "Ikki Yako",
        "year": "1993"
       },
       {
        "id": "EO3",
        "title": "Monsters",
        "year": "1994"
       }
    
      ],
      "Nationality": "Japanese"
     }
    ]
```

In my JMeter Test plan, I have defined a CSV Data Set Config file to store the ids of all authors in my system. 
And then, there is a Thread Group. Inside thread group, I have a HTTP Sampler, GET /authors/{id}/books. for Example GET /authors/1/books. This will get all the books written by author "William Shakespeare".

Using JSON Extractor, I can capture the array of book ids returned by GET /authors/{id}/books.

There are 3 books with ids WS1, WS2 and WS3. Now for each of the books, I need to run another HTTP Sampler

PUT /books/WS1
PUT /books/WS2
PUT /books/WS3.

When I use ForEach controller, I can specify the input variable which was captured from previous JSON extractor. And it loops through each PUT request, for each book id. I want to do the same, but in PARALLEL, not sequential.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? or we have to write custom groovy/BeanShell script for this? If custom Groovy/BeanShell script is the only way, can you please tell me how to write this

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by placing each test in a separate threadGroup.

You have a flag in the main test plan that controls if threads are executed in parallel or consecutively.

[image: test Plan configuration]

Comment: my requirement is different. I have edited my question adding more details.

Answer (score 0):

You're using not very correct test element, consider switching to [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler) instead.

Given you have the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
book_1=WS1
book_2=WS2
book_3=WS3
book_matchNr=3
```

[image]

You can add a Parallel Sampler and configure it to hit URLs containing `${book_1}`, `${book_2}` and `${book_3}`

[image]

All the `URLs to Retrieve` will be executed in parallel:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)

Comment: the solution you offered works when the number of books are constant, 3 in this case. in my data, this number varies, anything from 0 . so how do I dynamically add the URLs to the Parallel Sampler

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically add URLs to *Parallel HTTP Requests sampler*.

1. Add *JSR223 PreProcessor* like a child to *Parallel HTTP Requests sampler*.
2. To script area add something like that:

```
String url = "https://examle.url.com/?book=";

1.upto(vars.get('book_matchNr') as int, { 
    index -> {
        sampler.addURL(url + vars.get('book_' + index))
    }
});
```