# How to use parallel controller to execute list of urls

Tags: jmeter

I have extracted list of URLs from response to jmeter variable url

```
url_1 example.com
url_2 jmeter.apache.org
url_3 jmeter.plugins.org
```

Now I need to execute dynamic request with these urls based on the count using parallel controller.
Example As we have 3 urls in response, below requests need to be executed in parallel. If count is 5 then 5 url need to executed in parallel.

```
request1  example.com
request2 jmeter.apache.org
request3 jmeter-plugins.org
```

Can you please help me in this regar.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075139/parallel-execution-of-samplers-in-jmeter-with-different-url-parameters without upvoted/accepted answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use Parallel Controller for this, you can consider switching to [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler).

If you have a dynamic list of URLs coming from a [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) you can "feed" these URLs to the Parallel Sampler using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following code:

```
1.upto(vars.get('url_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    sampler.addURL(vars.get('url_' + index))
})
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)